# Replace double quotes and space using sed

Tags: linux, unix

I'm on rhel5 and have the following problem:
I have a function which replaces all the content from a given line with the text i want it to. Everything works fine till i need double quotes to be placed. following is the code:

```
ReplaceLine()
{
       txnFile="File.xml"
        if [ "$2" == "enable" ];then
                replace="<ref bean=\\"$3\\"/>"
        else
                replace="<!--<ref bean=\\"$3\\"/>-->"
        fi
        sed -i "$1s/.*/$replace/" $txnFile 
}

$1=line number
$2=enable/disable
$3=string to be put
```

Current code replaces the given line in the file with this:

```
<ref bean=beginEventBean/>
```

What i want is this:

```
<ref bean="beginEventBean"/>
```

Notice the missing double quotes. Also i used double quotes in sed as without them the spaces in the variables were causing sed to throw errors.

Please help me understand where i'm going the wrong way. Spent hours on this already.

Comment: `sed -i "$1s#.*#\"$replace\"#" $txnFile`

Comment: Khachik your idea worked!! put it below so i can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to escape the forward slash closing the tag. And you put two many slashes.

```
# one line solution
# sed -i "$1s/.*/<ref bean=\"$3\"\/>/" $txnFile
#                          ^   ^ ^

ReplaceLine()
{
     txnFile="File.xml"
     if [ "$2" == "enable" ];then
            replace="<ref bean=\"$3\"\/>"
     else
            replace="<!--<ref bean=\"$3\"\/>-->"
     fi
     sed -i "$1s/.*/$replace/" $txnFile 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the source line, I cannot test my solutions. Nevertheless, the following line is definitely not doing what you think:

```
replace="<ref bean=\\"$3\\"/>"
        ^          ^ ^
        |          | |
start quoted       | |
           backslash |
            end quoted
```

Add one more backslash, or delete one.

Comment: source line is any random text in the same tag.
and adding or removing a backslash throws a sed error.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work:

```
replace="<ref bean=\"$3\"\/>"
```

Note only one backslash (you escape the double quotes) and the backslash before the / character (you escape it for sed to use it as regular character, not the metacharacter used in replace command of sed)

Comment: It depends also on shell used / I tested it on bash and no errors... well, at least you solved it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed -i "$1s#.*#\"$replace\"#" $txnFile`. Note that it uses `#` instead of `/` as a separator for SED, because `$replace` contains `/`. Also, the answer by @choroba makes sense. Make sure your code does exactly what you want and does not work "accidently".